# Leaflet draw:drawvertex doesn't delete last point inserted

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I've tried deleting the last point while creatring a polygon but it only deletes the point but not the line that connects the last added and the previous.

```
map.on('draw:drawvertex', function(e){
            var layers = e.layers;
            layers.eachLayer(function (layer) {
                var ponto = turf.point([layer._latlng.lng, layer._latlng.lat]);
                var intersects = turf.intersect(polyPai2, ponto);
                if (intersects == null){
                    layer.remove(map);
                }
            });   
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation.
What i've done its update the polyline second point also to the first point so the line is between the point to itself (and therefore is not visible).
Maybe you can try doing somthing like this.
Hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you! And how do i replace the value? through id?